# How can I change the homepage address when I deploy my application in production and hosting server?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services

I  am working on a Spring web application. In my localmachine, the address I was using to see the home page is localhost:8080/ProjectName/mvc/template. But now in production if some one enter www [dot] myWebsite [dot] com I want them to take to the home page. How can I fix this?

This is how my web.xml looks

```
<web-app version="2.2" id="WebApp_ID">

    <!-- <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp</welcome-file>   
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: it's a matter of web-container configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tomcat you should set your deployment's context path.

First, open your tomcat web application manager and undeploy default tomcat page which path is "/".

Go deploy section in that page,
Write your context path "/".
And add your war file url to WAR or Directory URL box.
Deploy it.

Comment: Yes, I am using tomcat. Could you add more details, if possible?. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: I don't want to store my war file in production environment. I upload the war from my desktop to remote tomcat server.

Comment: It shouldn't have to be in your production environment. You can upload your file to different url adress and then u will enter that adress.

Comment: I am yet to do the above step. Once it works I will mark it as working answer. Could you answer this question, if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497719/should-i-change-value-of-mongo-bean-when-deploying-in-production-server

Comment: I did that. 
But, now if I enter 111.111.111.111:8080/mvc/pageName, I could access the homepage. 
Earlier, it use to be 111.111.111.111:8080/myprojectName/mvc/pageName.
 But what I want is 111.111.111.111:8080 should be taken to homepage of my website. How to do this?