# Should I change value of mongo bean when deploying in production server?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, tomcat

So, I am deploying my spring web app in tomcat server in production environment. I have my production server ip address. Should I replace the value of mongo bean from localhost to my ipaddress, in order to access the db?

```
<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>
```

What else should I change, in order to make my web app work with mongodb in production environment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all the relevant details in wht mongo bean to point to your production database. If you are hosting it externally (i.e. not on localhost) then you need to point it to URL and potentially port as well to ensure you have connectivity.
Don't forget login details as well, i've made that mistake a lot of times.

Comment: I am hosting my website with a hosting service. They gave me a linux server where I have installed mongodb and tomcat(having the webapp). How can I find out if I need to give localhost or url?

Comment: This information you would need to ask your hosting service provider as they all have different hosting setups. For e.g. one of mine i left as localhost and it works, where as for another i had to specify a dedicated URL